# Unity workspace-switcher (super+s) background color

Tags: unity, 16.04, workspace-switcher

When switching workspaces (super+s) the background of the view of all workspaces is black. Since I have a black background on my workspaces this gives kind of a bad contrast making the workspaces hard to see.
Is it possible to change the background of the workspace switcher?

Comment: If not already install compizconfig-settings-manager & open (ccsm). There are a number of appearance settings for the expo plugin, maybe you can improve, eg. enable a reflection & set a color, raise the brightness or saturation of the inactive workspaces, ect. I don't believe you can change the overall background color per se, at least not in settings.

Comment: Actually - if you raise the reflection ground size to 0.75 or even 1.0 then your chosen reflection color can surround the workspaces. Note I look at this with a 1x4 so ws's are in a line in middle of expo

Comment: @doug Perfect! There were settings to give me something good enough.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open [***compiz config manager***](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/)
2. ***Expo***.
3. ***Appearance Tab***.
4. ***Interactive view ports*** section.
5. increase ***Brightness***.

[image]